# @types - array of values to object keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Let's say I have a list of strings

```
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

How exactly do I convert it to an object in such a way that these values will be a key to any object?

```
const obj = {
 a: "can be anything",
 b: 2,
 c: 0
}
```

I have tried using

```
type TupleToObject<T extends readonly string[]> = {
    [P in T[number]]: any;
};
```

but it doesn't seemed to be strongly typed.

Comment: The fact that `arr` is a constant does not mean that the elements within the array can't be changed. What would you expect to happen if, during runtime, someone appended `"d"` to the array? TypeScript has no runtime type checking, so the question as stated is a bit ambiguous in terms of the expected result.

Comment: If you just want to specify the allowed property names, then you can use a type like `type keys = "a" | "b" | "c";` and then `const obj:Record<keys, unknown> = {`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of the `as const` TypeScript syntax ([See doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-inference)).

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"] as const;
// inferred type: readonly ["a", "b", "c"]


type TupleToObject<T extends readonly string[]> = {
    [P in T[number]]: any;
};

type MyObject = TupleToObject<typeof arr>
// type MyObject = {
//     a: any;
//     b: any;
//     c: any;
// }
```